# it's possible add hover on buttons in outlook 2010?

Tags: html-email, outlook-2010, vml

Hi I'm trying to show a button in an email campaign using outlook 2010 as a client and vml as a markup language but i can't reproduce the hover effect.

This is my code

```
 <!--[if mso]>
   <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas- microsoft-com:office:word" arcsize="13%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#6DC497"   style="height:50px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:170px;"   onmouseover="this.fillcolor='#6DC000'" >
    <w:anchorlock />
     <center style="width:100%;" >
    <![endif]-->
     buy it!
    <!--[if mso]>
   </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->
```

As you can see I use *onmouseover* property but it doesn't work.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not possible because [Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013 do not support the `:hover` attribute](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).**

Things like JavaScript and *onmouseover* generally aren't supported in any email client. VML is useful for hacking visual effects like gradients and background images in desktop Outlook, but I haven't heard it being used for interaction.